# PyQt5: painting using events

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter

I am new on PyQt I am working on a project on which I should implement a feature that make the user able to draw a digit using the mouse (digit recognition system). So what I want is when the mouse button is pressed the app will start to draw till the button is released. I made this source code but it is still not working (I think I am struggling with sending a signal to `PaintEvent()`).

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore 
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog,QGraphicsView,QGraphicsScene,QVBoxLayout

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication



class Communicate(QObject): 
    drawApp = pyqtSignal() 

class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI() 

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Simple')
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(500, 40)
        self.c = Communicate()
        self.c.drawApp.connect(self.PaintEvent())  

        self.show()


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        self.c.drawApp.emit()
        self.startingposx = event.x()
        self.startingposy = event.y()
        #super().mousePressEvent(event)
        print ("mouse pressed")


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        self.label.setText('Coordinates: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()) )
        self.y = event.y()
        self.x=event.x()  


    def PaintEvent(self,event):

           qp = QPainter()  
           qp.begin(self)

           #qp.setPen(Qt.red)
           qp.drawPoints(self,qp)
           qp.end()

           self.update()



    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        self.endingposx = event.x()
        self.endingposy = event.y()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        print("starting point was",self.startingposx)
        print("starting point y was ",self.startingposy)
        print("ending point was ",self.endingposx)
        print("ending point was y ",self.endingposy)
        print("released")    



    def drawPoints(self,qp):

          qp.setPen(Qt.red)
          size = self.size()
          x=self.x
          y=self.y
          qp.drawPoint(x,y)     

app = QApplication(sys.argv)


widget = MyWidget()

widget.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is sensitive to uppercase and lowercase so be more careful, the method is called `paintEvent`.

Also you should not call `paintEvent` directly, you must use the function `update()`, this method will internally call `paintEvent()`.

But even correcting that error your problem is not solved, if you want to draw a path it is advisable to use `QPainterPath` as this stores the strokes.

```
class Drawer(QWidget):
    newPoint = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.path = QPainterPath()    

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPath(self.path)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.path.moveTo(event.pos())
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.path.lineTo(event.pos())
        self.newPoint.emit(event.pos())
        self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(400, 400)

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        label = QLabel(self)
        drawer = Drawer(self)
        drawer.newPoint.connect(lambda p: label.setText('Coordinates: ( %d : %d )' % (p.x(), p.y())))
        self.layout().addWidget(label)
        self.layout().addWidget(drawer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: eyllanesc please man how to set the background of the QPainting object 
I tried : but it is not working 

def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QColor(168, 34, 3))
        painter.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 10))
        bbrush = QtGui.QBrush( QtGui.QColor(0,0,0), 
                      QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        painter.setBackground(painter,bbrush)
        painter.drawPath(self.path)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to reply to [eyllanesc's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) solution, but in case others are having issues, the imports were not complete. Here's is [eyllanesc's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) solution with the imports. It will execute without error:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QLabel, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QPoint, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class Drawer(QWidget):
    newPoint = pyqtSignal(QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.path = QPainterPath()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPath(self.path)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.path.moveTo(event.pos())
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.path.lineTo(event.pos())
        self.newPoint.emit(event.pos())
        self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(400, 400)


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        label = QLabel(self)
        drawer = Drawer(self)
        drawer.newPoint.connect(lambda p: label.setText('Coordinates: ( %d : %d )' % (p.x(), p.y())))
        self.layout().addWidget(label)
        self.layout().addWidget(drawer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```